# How to print a key from dictionary

Tags: python

I have following code which is used to get news articles from google news:

```
import newsapi
import requests

from newsapi.articles import Articles

a = Articles(API_KEY="api key goes here")

res= a.get_by_top(source='google-news')

results= res['articles']

print(results)
```

It returns me results as a dict with following entries for all articles are displayed.

```
"author": "Rachel Kaser",
"title": "AOL Instant Messenger to shut down after 20 years",
"description": "AOL announced that its iconic chat service from the '00s is officially going dark after 20 years -- and we're sad to see it go.",
"url": "https://thenextweb.com/socialmedia/2017/10/06/aol-instant-messenger-shut-down/",
"urlToImage": "https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2017/10/AIM-social.jpg",
"publishedAt": "2017-10-06T16:13:02Z"
```

What I want to do is to get only `title` and `description`not all the entries. I don't know how to do it. 
I tried `results=res['articles'['description']]` which gave me error "*list indices must be int or slice, str given*"

and `results=res['articles'[2]]` which returns above mentioned results for 3rd article in the list.

Both did not work for me.

Can anybody tell me how to do it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `print(json.loads(results)['author']))` | `print(results['author'])`

Comment: Is `results` a string or a dict?

Comment: @Rawing it is a Dict

Comment: @Torxed it gives me the same error. TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: If it's a dict, then this isn't json, it's just a dict. json is a _string representation_ of data.

Comment: I am guessing the response is a string. You need to convert it into a json object. You can use `json.loads` and then print the value of a key.

Comment: I apologize for leading you to a misconception. It is a list. as it gave me error TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'list' 
Please don't mind about my previous comment.

Comment: @Tauseef_Ahmed The apis normally return JSONstrings which can have various formats. This is a list with dictionaries if you read it into Python with JSON library. You should however have a look at the Pandas library, see my answer below. It is by far the most efficient way to deal with these issues.

Comment: @Tauseef_Ahmed So it is a list of dictionaries? `for dct in list_of_dcts: print(dct["author"])`

Answer (score 1):

You can create your dict from the `result` using dict comprehension:

```
res = {k: v for k, v in d.iteritems() if k in ['title', 'url']}
print res

{'url': 'https://thenextweb.com/socialmedia/2017/10/06/aol-instant-messenger-shut-down/', 
'title': 'AOL Instant Messenger to shut down after 20 years'}
```

Switch `d.iteritems()` with `res['articles'].iteritems()`

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: @Tauseef_Ahmed you welcome. If you've found my answer (or any other answer posted to your question) please kindly consider upvoting it and accepting the answer which helped you solve your question

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to iterate over the results and extract these pairs of values from each.

I presume that this `Article.get_by_top()` method is receiving JSON text and performing the *load* (parsing, "deserialization") on it.  So you're getting a dictionary containing, probably among other things, a key named *articles* which is associated with a list value.  Each item in that list would be a dictionary conforming to your example.

Here's your code with the suggested changes to try:

```
import newsapi
import requests
from newsapi.articles import Articles

a = Articles(API_KEY="api key goes here")
res = a.get_by_top(source='google-news')
## Was: results = res['articles']
##      print(results)
results = [(each['title'],each['description']) for each in res['articles']]
print('\n'.join(['%s\n\t%s' % (title, desc) for title, desc in results])
# Untested!
```

This uses a couple of list comprehensions (a bit of syntactic sugar in Python). That's the same as if we'd use more explicit code like:

```
results = list()
for each in res['articles']:
    results.append((each['title'],each['description']))
    # A list of tuples, each containing two items

# Print results:
for title, desc in results:
    # We're using Python's handy "tuple unpacking" syntax here
    print('%s\n\t%s' % (title, desc))
```

I hope that helps.  However the tenor of your question suggest that you'll need to study a Python tutorial before this makes any sense to you.

ReST APIs typically have data structured in several layers of nesting such as this. Dictionaries containing lists of dictionaries containing more dictionaries and lists.  Learning how to traverse such structures is a large part of modern web programming.

Answer (score 0):

Althought his answer isn't "exactly" what you asked for this is **by far** the "way" to do it (my opinion). Use the pandas library.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

sample = [{"author": "Rachel Kaser",
"title": "AOL Instant Messenger to shut down after 20 years",
"description": "AOL announced that its iconic chat service from the '00s is officially going dark after 20 years -- and we're sad to see it go.",
"url": "https://thenextweb.com/socialmedia/2017/10/06/aol-instant-messenger-shut-down/",
"urlToImage": "https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2017/10/AIM-social.jpg",
"publishedAt": "2017-10-06T16:13:02Z"},{"author": "Rachel Kaser",
"title": "AOL Instant Messenger to shut down after 20 years",
"description": "AOL announced that its iconic chat service from the '00s is officially going dark after 20 years -- and we're sad to see it go.",
"url": "https://thenextweb.com/socialmedia/2017/10/06/aol-instant-messenger-shut-down/",
"urlToImage": "https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2017/10/AIM-social.jpg",
"publishedAt": "2017-10-05T16:13:02Z"}]
```

Short version

```
# Load to panda and export in one row
res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample)[["title","description"]].T.to_dict().values()
print(res)
```

Long version with endless options

```
# Load it to pandas (a table)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample)

# Optional...
# You can also filter data, for instance date
# Can also look for words, authors, anything...
df["publishedAt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["publishedAt"])
df[df["publishedAt"] > datetime.date(2017,10,6)] # publised after 2017,10,6

# Now you can do the last removal - what you really asked for
df = df[["title","description"]]

# Export options:

#df.to_csv("output.csv",index=False)
#df.to_dict(orient="index")
#df.to_html()
#df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Upvoting because this shows how Pandas can be used for general purpose data processing operations outside of data analytics and numerically focused applications.

Comment: @JimDennis That's exactly my point. I wish pandas got the attention it deserves for all table-like operations. Had the OP had some basic knowledge about pandas he/she would have solved the question in a second. Thanks :)

Comment: @AntonvBR: if the OP were using pd.from_dict() they wouldn't have to understand much about JSON and the wildly nested data structures that are typical for ReST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I notice there is a pattern in fetched data so i tried with my result and your result, It worked as you want : You can do it with regex :

```
import newsapi
import requests
import json
import re

from newsapi.articles import Articles

a = Articles(API_KEY="Key goes here")

res= a.get_by_top(source='google-news')

results= res['articles']


dump_data=json.dumps(results)

title=r'("title":\s{0,5}["]\w.*?["])'
description=r'("description":\s{0,5}["]\w.*?["])'

description_1=re.search(description,dump_data,re.M)
title_1=re.search(title,dump_data,re.M)


print("{} \n{}".format(title_1.group(),description_1.group()))
```

output:

```
"title": "Nate at Hurricane Strength as Region Faces $1 Billion Damage" 
"description": "Hurricane Nate, on track to strike near New Orleans overnight Saturday, is threatening to cause close to $1 billion in damage across Central America and the U.S. following the most powerful month of hurricanes on record."
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will test your solution.

Comment: @Tauseef_Ahmed  if my solution works for you, You can accept my answer. Thanks :)